# Uploading files with PHP on a linux machine

Tags: php, linux, raspbian, user-permissions

I'm trying to make some sort of cloud application on a headless raspbian machine.
The testing happens on a wamp-server running on windows8.1. PHP version is 5.6

The code works fine on my testing windows, but I run into issues when running the same code on my linux server. I've narrowed down the issue to the fact that (the linux user behind) my PHP code doesn't have write permissions on the folder where it should store files.

I can think of two ways to solve the issue: either give that php-user permissions, or change the user behind the php code. The last one would be quite interesting if it was possible to change per-script.

So, for my concrete question:

1) Where can I find what user is being used by my PHP code?

2) Can I change what user my PHP code uses, preferably on a per-project basis?

EDIT:

My script was running as root, as is shown by `echo get_current_user();`. I changed ownership of all files to root:webhosting, which was previously ftpuser:ftpgroup. However, when setting permissions to `770` I get access denied

EDIT2:

When using `var_dump(posix_geteuid());` instead of `get_current_user();`, i get UID 33, which matches user www-data.

SOLUTION:

By looking at the EUID with [`var_dump(posix_geteuid();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php) I was able to validate the actual user, which does NOT match the `get_current_user();`. Changing the directroy and all files in it with `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data <root of site>` I managed to set the correct permissions.

Comment: Do you know what web server you are running? If so, you can see who is running it. For example, I run `ps aux | grep httpd` and it shows me that user "apache" is running httpd. So, I have to give apache permission to read/write folders.

Comment: 1) you can try http://de.php.net/get_current_user

2) well, no

Comment: like Sebastian said you can user `echo get_current_user();` to show the current user. are you having the permission issue in the initial tmp folder or the destination folder? to change you can do `chown user | chmod 755 /var/www/html/myuploaddir` also you might be interested in the owncloud project which is an open-source lamp cloud project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the specifics are but normally when I have issues like that I change the ownership to www-data:www-data and if necessary for upload folders I change the folder permissions to 0755 and inside files permissions to 0644.

**EDIT**

I changed the permissions setting for security purposes.

Comment: 777 is terrible advice, usually opening the server up to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Goose well, sometimes it's necessary 0755 could work too.

Comment: The executable bit on files can often cause security issues. 644 on files and 755 on folders is much more standard. 664 and 775 is sometimes necessary.

Comment: I'll add, 777 is never necessary. Also, considering he's doing file uploads, it's even more important to use secure file permissions. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109674/apart-from-uploaded-files-how-else-can-777-permissions-on-website-files-folders

Comment: Found out that the user is indeed www-data with group www-data. My personal opinion on this is: NEVER EVER use 777 unless you want the file deleted by anyone thats able to see it.

Comment: @Goose It solved my problem. And he mentioned "if necessary" wich is kinda maybe possibly enough of a warning for most people, and there is most likely some use-case for it. Sad that you can only mark one answer as the solution, because your answer is valid as well.

Comment: @sniker824 You should mark the best correct answer, not the first correct answer. Not trying to ask for your check mark, just a friendly heads up.

Comment: I added the 0777 because I've stumbled upon pieces of software that demand certain folders to have 0777 permissions since the installation process and they don't let you proceed unless you configure it so. I personally use 0775 or 0755 depending on the specifics.

Comment: Many people will find this answer, use it as is, and end up with a trivial to find and exploit security vulnerability. You should edit your answer to caution on the dangers of 777, if not remove it outright. If any software tells you to keep your files as 777 in production, it is insecure. 755, 753, and 751 is insecure to set on files, as files should never have it's executable bit set unless it's intended to be used by the shell, in which case other security measures are needed to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

You're PHP/Apache user is probably `www-data`. You probably want to run something like this.

```
sudo find path/to/project/ -exec chown www-data:root {} \;
```

File permissions may also be a problem. If so, run something like this.

```
sudo find path/to/project/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find path/to/project/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Comment: Also seems like a valid solution. however I changed it to www-data:www-data and added myself to that group. Is that a better or worse way to fix it, considering the account i use is a full admin account to (almost) the same level as root is? +1 for using the find commando like that

Comment: I'd suggest against adding yourself to www-data, it's general a good idea to separate the human system user from the webserver system user. Most likely won't matter, but let's say you get hacked, would be good to know if they hacked the webserver or if they just hacked your ssh. And yeah, I personally prefer find over -recursive flags.